# Changing "menu bar" div from relative to static using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this site that has a 100% width div approximately 700px from top of page. When user scrolls page down and reaches the menu, it changes to fixed and stays on top of page until user scrolls up back. I have implemented this code I found on http://jsbin.com/omanut/2 :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var fixit = document.querySelector('.topmenu');
    var origOffsetY = fixit.offsetTop;

    function onScroll(e) {
    window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? fixit.classList.add('topfix') :
                              fixit.classList.remove('topfix');
    }

    document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

    </script>
```

"topmenu" is a unique class I used for the menu bar div element. "topfix" is a class defined inside some html < style > tag:

```
    <style>

    .topfix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    }

    </style>
```

As you can see, this code shall add "topfix" as class for the div in question. So my html should change from < div class="topmenu" > to < div class="topmenu topfix" >. IT WORKS BEAUTIFULLY GREAT on Chrome and Firefox BUT I cannot make it work on IE. I'm a noob with programming but I think there could be something missing for adding an event listener that would work on IE. I will appreciate the help.

--After some answers, I made some modifications to the script; it is cool on Chrome/FF but still does not work on IE, so here you have it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fixit = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[3];
var origOffsetY = fixit.offsetTop;

function onTopScroll(e) {
window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? fixit.classList.add('topfix') :
                          fixit.classList.remove('topfix');
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', onTopScroll);
document.attachEvent('onscroll', onTopScroll);

</script>
```

I'm not sure about attachEvent syntax. Any further help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of your IE?. `document.querySelector()` is not supported in every IE. You can use `getElementsByTagName` and match for the particular class and then do your thing.

Comment: I changed  querySelector for  var fixit = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i]; in this case i = 3, and still works on Chrome, but does not solve for IE. But I will keep it, thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, IE8. The line where addEventListener is located, reports an error.

Comment: Upgraded to IE9. Errors disappeared, but script does not work or at least doesn't seems to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

try attachEvent for IE not addEventListener

Comment: I'm trying to use attachEvent but it still does not work on IE; I should check the syntax.